# HTML parser not working in SOLR 3.6

Tags: solr

Using the solr.jar with the example in the download for Apache Solr 3.6, the HTML tags are not getting stripped.

In schema.xml I added the following:

```
<!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
<fieldType name="text_html" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="title" type="text_html" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Also, I posted the following JSON to SOLR:

```
[
{
    "id" : "978-064172344522",

    "title":"my <a href=\"www.foo.bar\">link</a>  power-shot PowerShot USC Utility <br>hello</br> Rejections Under 35 U.S.C. 101 and 35 U.S.C. 112, First Paragraph Petitions to correct inventorship of an issued patent are decided by the <Underline>Supervisory Patent Examiner</Underline>, as set forth"

}
```

]

After restarting SOLR, I conducted a search for power-shot and the results still show the HTML tags

```
 <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="0.13561106">
 <doc>
 <float name="score">0.13561106</float>
 <str name="id">978-064172344522</str>
 <arr name="title">
 <str>my <a href="www.foo.bar">link</a> power-shot PowerShot USC Utility <br>hello</br>
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

what you see is the field Stored as originally sent to Solr. If you search for 'title:href' for example, you should not find the document, as in the Analyzer chain html stuff should be removed

Comment: The problem is that highlighting is returning the HTML tags in the snippet. I would like the results from highlighting to remove the HTML tags. How do I get it do display snippets without HTML tags.  `<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="978-064172344522">
<arr name="title"> 
<str>
my <a href="www.foo.bar">link</a> <em>power</em>-<em>shot</em> <em>PowerShot</em> USC Utility <br>hello</br> Rejections Under
</str>
</arr>
</lst>
</lst>`

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to do what you want. Highlighting adds the <em> tags anyway. you cold post process and remove tags you don't want